# Merging data from 2 arrays to a new array as object -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, one consists of all the States of a Country and the other has all the Districts of every States.

array1 has all the States and its data as below :

```
stateArray = [ {state1data1: info, state1data2: info}, {state2data1: info, state2data2: info} ]
```

array2 has all the Districts and its data of each State as below :

```
districtArray = [ {state1district1: {districtData}, state1district2: {districtData} }, {state2district1: {districtData}, state2district2: {districtData} } ]
```

Data from both arrays can be identified using its Index value. Like if stateArray has a State in index 0, then districtArray has all the Districts from that particular State in index 0.

Now I am trying to create a new Array, which will get the States from stateArray and District data of that particular State from districtArray and add is as statedata. Something like this:

```
array3 = [ {state1data1: info, state1data2: info, state1districtdata: {state1district1: {districtData}, state1district2: {districtData} } }]
```

I am clueless about how to achieve this. I will be thankful if anyone can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array3 = [];
for(let i = 0; i < districtArrray.length; i++) {
    let obj = {... stateArray[i]};
    obj[i].state1districtdata = districtArray[i];
    array3.push(obj);
}
```